# SO Election positive feedback loop

Tags: discussion, election

I just clicked on to [2014 SO Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) and scrolled down the answers the candidates have posted, which got me thinking...

Doesn't having the ordering of the answers in the standard SE most-votes-first *in this context* provide you with an unhelpful [positive feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback) loop?

Surely in this case it wouldn't be better to have a un-ordered list (like in the nomination process) such that contenders who post answers later are not "penalized" by being at the bottom of the page?

I know in an ideal world everyone would read all the responses, but we don't and people are lazy and are more likely to read the top couple and hence they are more likely to receive votes.

Comment: People shouldn't vote on the questionnaire answers at all, imo.

Comment: You can order by "oldest" or "active" if you really want.

Comment: You can always resort on 'active' and 'oldest' if you are worried about reading the posts in a different order. But we cannot disable voting on a given post here without also disabling commenting and answering, so we'll just have to live with it.

Comment: Anyway, it only affects their meta rep, it has nothing to do with the election itself.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Closing or protecting the question wouldn't prevent votes.  Locking it would, but that would prevent the candidates from answering or editing their posts.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian On Arqade the votes on the questionnaire were actually cleared after people in the main chat felt like it was working against the whole idea.

Comment: @Kevin It does have to do with the election itself as people are much more likely to read the posts on top of the page, and the people who would bother changing the sorting will most likely read all the answers anyway.

Comment: Order it any way you like it; it remains a huge wall of text. Is this now meta-meta?

Comment: It's not just ordering of reading responses that's a problem. People can also just look at the voting and likely get a sense of which candidates are popular in the real election (an election where, mind you, the votes are deliberately completely secret until afterwards).